# Fail to run websocket server

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I try to run my websocket server but it fails to run for some reason I cant figure out.
I used this tutorial: http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world

I have this main folder:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fZNf.png)

**composer.js:**

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "dealspace_websocket\\": "websocket_src"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4.2"
    }
}
```

Inside `websocket_src` folder, there is ONLY 1 file, **Chat.php**:

```
<?php
namespace dealspace_websocket;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
require_once __DIR__ . "/../Model/DBConnection.php";

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $JSonMsg = json_decode($msg);
        if($JSonMsg['type'] === 'updownvote') {
            $connection = new DBConnection();
            $allowUpdate = false;
            try {
                $sql = 'UPDATE `deals`
                        SET `votes_counter` = :vc
                        WHERE `id` = :id';
                $stmt = $connection->dbh->prepare($sql);
                $allowUpdate = $stmt->execute(array(
                    'vc' => $JSonMsg['data']['votes'],
                    'id' => $JSonMsg['data']['dealid']
                ));
                if($allowUpdate !== false) {
                    $dataOBJ->dealid = $JSonMsg['data']['dealid'];
                    $dataOBJ->votes = $JSonMsg['data']['votes'];
                    $returnMsg->type = 'updownvote';
                    $returnMsg->date = $dataOBJ;
                    foreach($this->clients as $client) {
                        $client->send(json_encode($returnMsg));
                    }
                }
            } catch(PDOException $e) {}
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

And the last file, **websocket_server.php**:

```
<?php
    use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
    use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
    use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
    use dealspace_websocket\Chat;

    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new Chat()
            )
        ),
        8080
    );

    $server->run();
?>
```

Then, when I open the CMD in the main folder, I run: `php websocket_server.php`

This is the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgFo3.png)

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are `require`-ing the `vendor/autoload.php` file after `use`-ing the classes.

Put the `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` at the top of the file and PHP will be able to find the classes.

```php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use dealspace_websocket\Chat;
```

**EDIT**

---

There is also one crucial part that i did not notice at first, which is the typo in `composer.json`, you need to prefix the path to which the *namespace* points with a `/` to tell composer to look for files under the given directory.

The resulted `json` would be:

```
"psr-4": {
    "dealspace_websocket\\": "websocket_src/"
}
```

After making this change run [`composer dump-autoload`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-)

> You can read more about PSR-4 autoloading [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4) and [here](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

Comment: @QwertTrewq Please check the edit and tell me if it solved your problem.

Comment: It worked after running `composer dump-autload` without making the change.. Why this command was necessary?

Comment: Each time you add/remove a dependency, namespace or even `classmap`s you need to run the `composer dump-autoload` command which dumps the old autoload file and creates a new one containing all of the autoloaded classes.

Comment: Would you try creating a class in the same root namespace then importing it in the presented class? As much as i am aware of this should not work because the `dealspace_websocket` namespace is not autoloded.